# Crystal Lang project directory structure conventions

Tags: crystal-lang

Are there any conventions regarding project directory structure?

I have a project that was initialized with `crystal init app [project-name]`. Inside of that is the `src` directory which has the folders for modules and classes. However, now I want to add an ORM which will require a models directory. What conventions are there for laying this out?

Right now I've created a sub-directory inside of `src` called `modules` where classes and modules are going.

Comment: "sub-directory ... called modules where classes and modules are going": This doesn't seem to make much sense. Classes and modules are the content of the entire `src` directory, why would you put them in a subpath?

Comment: I wanted to differentiate between general classes and models and views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct answer here. It very much depends on the pattern you want to follow. If you are using a framework like lucky or amber, I would suggest referring to their documentation as both prefer a conventional (rather than configurable) approach. Both follow a rails'esque convention.

```
[root]
  ⌙ /src
    ⌙ /models
    ⌙ /controllers
    ⌙ /views
```

If you are implementing services DDD like modules, then I would suggest:

```
[root]
  ⌙ /src
    ⌙ /[service/module a]
    ⌙ /[service/module b]
```